# ORACLE trigger before procedure execution

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, triggers

Is it possible to fire a trigger before a specific procedure starts execution?
For example  I have a package `"A"`, and a procedure `"B"` inside package `"A"`.
So when I call A.B procedure i want to fire a trigger.
I'm using oracle 11gR2.

Comment: And what is that trigger supposed to do? What is the business logic you are trying to code? What you are trying to do, it seems `TRIGGER` is not at all required. You could use a procedure before executing the `A.B` procedure.

Comment: To quote TFM: You can write triggers that fire whenever one of the following operations occurs: DML statements (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) on a particular table or view, issued by any user

DDL statements (CREATE or ALTER primarily) issued either by a particular schema/user or by any schema/user in the database

Database events, such as logon/logoff, errors, or startup/shutdown, also issued either by a particular schema/user or by any schema/user in the database --- none of these spells "procedure call"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it possible to fire a trigger before a specific procedure starts execution?

No, you *cannot* **manually** fire a trigger without any **DML** operation on the table. Triggers are designed to act implicitly on any DML action. **Trigger is a (*side*)effect of an action and not an action in itself.**

I don't think you need a trigger for your requirement. You could call a **procedure** before executing the procedure `A.B`. Put your business logic accordingly. PL/SQL is a procedural language. So, if you put another procedure say procedure `C` before `A.B`, then `A.C` will be executed before `A.B`.

Answer (score 1):

Triggers cannot be called directly. Instead they are fired automatically when you perform an insert/update or delete on a table that has triggers. So like in your case, on calling  A.B procedure, you can perform an insert / update or delete that will force a trigger to fire.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an existing trigger on a table and you want its logic to be executed under other circumstances, then place the logic in a procedure and call that procedure from the trigger, and from any other code that needs to execute it.